# How to route the HTTP request using golang GIN based on request URL

Tags: go

For example there are two url

`http://user1?test`

`http://user1?test1`

I want to route "`http://user1?test`" to `func1()` and `http://user1?test1` to `func2()`.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter? Be specific, with error messages or actual output, and explain what you expected instead.

Answer (score 0):

so i have used gin router for routing the request.
its like router.POST("/user1?test",func())
but GIN is considering till "/user1" its not considering where "?" comes into picture. In short is it like GIN only considers "/" only not "?".

Comment: I don't believe you can route directly based on query parameters, but you are able to access them in your handler func using `c.Query("test")` https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Query